# Escape string for Lua's string.format

Tags: string, lua, escaping, lua-patterns

I have a string I need to add a variable to so I use the `string.format` method, but the string also contains the symbol `"%20"` (not sure what it represents, probably a white space or something). Anyway since the string contains multiple `"%"` and I only want to add the variable to the first one to set the id, is there a way to escape the string at the points or something?

As it is now:

```
ID = 12345
string.format("id=%s&x=foo=&bar=asd%20yolo%20123-1512", ID)
```

I get `bad argument #3 to 'format' (no value).` error -- since it expects 3 variables to be passed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can escape a `%` with another `%`, e.g. `string.format("%%20")` will give `%20`

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Unlike many other languages, Lua uses `%` to escape the following magic characters:

```
( ) . % + - * ? [ ] ^ $
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below escape all URL escapes (that is, % followed by a digit):

```
ID=12345
f="id=%s&x=foo=&bar=asd%20yolo%20123-1512"
f=f:gsub("%%%d","%%%1")
print(string.format(f,ID))
```

Comment: Why `%%%1` doesn't raise error?  There are no captured substrings here.  Only `%%%0` is possible according to Lua manual.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, the manual says "if the pattern specifies no captures, then it behaves as if the whole pattern was inside a capture.".

Answer (score 1):

I have seen you have accepted an answer, but really, this situation should almost never happen in a real application. You should try to avoid mixing patterns with other data.

If you have a string like this: `x=foo=&bar=asd%20yolo%20123-1512` and you want to prepend the ID part to it using `string.format`, you should use something like this:

```
s = "x=foo=&bar=asd%20yolo%20123-1512"
ID = 12345
string.format("id=%d&%s", ID, s)
```

(Note: I have used `%d` because your ID is a number, so it is prefered to `%s` in this case.)